# Apps Script While

Tags: google-apps-script

i want to create a loop that checks if the cell is "free" == 0.

IF the cell is not free go to the next cell. And the Cell is specified in the var cellcheckfin1.
IF its free wirte the Value in it.

I cant figure out why the loop doesn't end.

Thanks in advance

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var cellcheck ="P";
  var cellcheck1 = 4;
  var cellcheckfin1 = cellcheck + cellcheck1
  var check = 0


  while (check == 0) {
    var valcheck = sheet.getRange(cellcheckfin1).getValue();
    sheet.getRange('O4').setValue(valcheck);
    if(valcheck == 0){
      sheet.getRange(cellcheckfin1).setValue("ValueIWant");
      var check = 1;
      break
    }
    else if(valcheck != 0){
      var cellcheck1 = cellcheck1 + 1;
      continue
    }
  }
  
}
```

i want to create a loop that checks if the cell is "free" == 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question of `I cant figure out why the loop doesn't end.`, when I saw your script, `cellcheckfin1` is not changed. By this, the value of `cellcheckfin1` is always `P4`. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cellcheck = "P";
  var cellcheck1 = 4;
  // var cellcheckfin1 = cellcheck + cellcheck1
  var check = 0;
  while (check == 0) {
    var valcheck = sheet.getRange(cellcheck + cellcheck1).getValue();
    sheet.getRange('O4').setValue(valcheck);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    if (valcheck == 0) {
      sheet.getRange(cellcheck + cellcheck1).setValue("ValueIWant");
      var check = 1;
      break
    } else if (valcheck != 0) {
      var cellcheck1 = cellcheck1 + 1;
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

- By this, the cell range is changed. And, about `sheet.getRange('O4').setValue(valcheck);`, if you want to check the value in a cell, `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` might be required to be used.
- Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected situation, for example, the following modified script might be able to be also used.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range = sheet.getRange("P4:P" + lastRow).createTextFinder("0").matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
    if (!range) {
      range = sheet.getRange("P" + (lastRow + 1));
    }
    range.setValue("ValueIWant");
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks. hehe i wonder about how you understood my question i was really tilted last night. I got my code to work las night but yours work two. But can you explain please why it also "takes" the next empty cell and not only cells with 0 in it. And is there a way   you can cap the range of. Thanks in advance <3

Comment: @Simbon Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new 2 questions, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new 2 questions. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand your new 2 questions. When I could correctly understand your new 2 questions, I would like to try to think of the solutions. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon, because of my poor English skill. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hello, again I ain't from an English speaking Country too so, there is also the possibility that it's my languages fault u don't understand my questions. And as I red it now I understand u can't understand haha. I think it's fine now I had to do this for a friend of mine and he is satisfied by the result. Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @Simbon Thank you for replying and for your concern. I would like to study more for being able to answer various questions.

Comment: i understand if u want u can train at my new problem. :D Thanks for helping me.